# reload local module in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, reload

I know this is an old topic with many similar posts, but I haven't found any discussion on the specific issue that I am seeing.

I am importing and running a function in a local module:

```
from local.script import calculate_task
```

It has a bug and says something like: In line 100, "yyy = xx * 2", Error: variable xx not defined.

It is a typo, the variable should be xxx. So I fixed it in local.script. Following what I found online, I did:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
from local.script import calculate_task
```

Now it is the weird thing: the code still fails, but it says something like: In line 100, "yyy = xxx * 2", Error: variable xx not defined.

So in the console print, the script seems to be updated, but the code is still running the old version with xx! I am really puzzled.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the kernel? this may clear the variables in the memory.

Comment: Restarting the kernel always works. But I am really puzzled what is going on...

Comment: I think restarting with newly added two magic commands (whose starts with %), and then changing variables xxx → xab will reflect the changes (without further restart needed).

Comment: Right, that's my puzzle. The console print says: In line 100, "yyy = xxx * 2", Error: variable xx not defined. So the variable in the script is right now (xxx), but the kernel still running the old version, hence throwing the "Error: variable xx not defined". In other words, the kernel is still running the old version with xx.